# `react-scripts start` keeps opening new tabs

Tags: reactjs, npm, create-react-app, windows-subsystem-for-linux, npm-scripts

I have a react project built with `create-react-app`. Everything is working fine, except that every few minutes it decides to open up http://localhost:3000/ in a new tab in the browser. This happens when I haven't made any changes to the code, and I already have http://localhost:3000/ open in another tab. How can I make this stop happening? I haven't been able to find any solutions.

I'm on Windows 10, WSL2.

I start up the project using `npm start`. This is my `package.json`:

```
{
  "name": "client",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {...},
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: there is some basic troubleshooting you can try. kill all terminals/restart, delete your node modules folder, and reinstall

Comment: @dovigz This has been happening for a while. I've turned my computer on and off multiple times. I'll try deleting/reinstalling though

Comment: @ariabr , did you get resolution. Happening in my Mac. I use pm2 to run the react app. Whenever I leave it for night, I see 100+ tabs opened up in morning and hangs chrome. No code changes done, no activity ever done during this period. No logs as well

Answer (score 0):

To disable create-react-app from opening a tab each time the application starts or compiles (which is what nodemon is triggering when files change) you can set the env variable to

```
BROWSER=none
```

If you're testing with create-react-app then you don't really need nodemon you can just do npm start and it will automatically rebuild and reload as you work on your code.

```
BROWSER=none npm start
```